# How to convert obfuscated jar file into respective Windows / Linux / Mac native code?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I know a good hacker can obtain the source code of my Java files but I want to at least make it difficult for any one else to do so.

I can use ProGuard to obfuscate my jar file and the next step is to convert the jar file into Windows exe, Ubuntu bin?, Mac Os ...

What are the free software to do so?

Comment: Note that you must ensure that you can unobfuscate stack traces.  This will be useful for bugreports.  Also EXE in the Java world are for easy launching  of code,  not for hiding the byte code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None at all. `java`-code is **always** compiled into `.class`-files, which are bundled into `.jar`-files. Just change the file-extension of a jar into `.zip` and try to open it. You can create a launcher for the app, but the app itself is written in java. Next point:
"A good hacker" isn't necessary. There are decompilers out there available to anyone, which can convert `.class`-files into readable java-files. Obfuscating code alters variable- and class-names in a way that makes them unusable for human readers; good obfuscators in addition alter the bytecode in a way that makes the code (nearly) decompileable. And `.exe` and the counterparts on Linux and Mac OS are decompile-able as well, so there isn't much use in it anyways.
In general: executable binaries more secure than a `.jar`-file. The vital point is to obfuscate the byte-code properly.

Comment: Good obfuscators rewrite byte code so decompilers cannot easily do pattern recognition on them.  It is possible to have a byte code sequence that does not map to a valid Java source.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen good point. I'll add that to my answer

Comment: @Paul Is ProGuard a good tool to "obfuscate the byte-code properly"?

Comment: @IsaacThang ProGuard isn't bad after all I've heard, but I haven't worked enough on that field, to give a reliable answer.